# PopView to the location on screen we were at

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, blackberry-playbook

I have a Blackberry playbook Flex app that has a form. There is a TextArea input that when "focused in", pushes a new view with a full screen text area. When that full screen text area is filled, a button is clicked and the screen is popped to the original form...

**The problem:**
When I pop this 2nd screen, it returns to the first form at the top, not retaining the view position we were at on the page... is there anyway to return to the part of the form we were editting?

Comment: PlayBook device is too buggy, I don't think you'll be able to do that. Putting +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the edit-view with a parameter [1] that contains the last scroll-coordinates and when poping [2] the view you could set these coordinates as return value, so the first form-view can scroll back down [3].

[1] The second argument of `pushView` takes any object:

```
navigator.pushView(EditView, {position:"someValue"});
```

[2] Override `createReturnObject` to create a return object when poping a view:

```
public function createReturnObject():Object
```

[3] in the viewActivate eventhandler the `data`-property will hold your pushed object.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from alopix's response I came up with the following solution that worked across the entire app. I have to extend the View class:

**MyView.as**

This was needed so that each time the view became active (was viewed), its verticalScrollPosition would be stored value in a global variable (shown next). "mainContent" is the ID of the MyGroup that stores everything on the actual MXML view (so we can track it and update its verticalScrollPosition).

```
public class MyView extends View
{

    public function MyView()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VIEW_ACTIVATE, goToCorrectViewpoint);
    }

    private function goToCorrectViewpoint(e:Event):void{
        trace("Setting vertical position to "+FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.verticalPositionTracker[this.title]);
        if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.verticalPositionTracker.hasOwnProperty(this.title))
            (this["mainContent"] as Group).verticalScrollPosition = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.verticalPositionTracker[this.title];
    }
}
```

**The Global variable for storing the verticalScrollPosition of each Page**

I had to store all the Y coordinates in a Global variable called verticalPositionTracker. This was just an Object of "Page Title" => verticalScrollPosition (eg. the Y Coordinate) e.g:

1. Login Page -> 120
2. Results Page ->200
3. etc...

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="view.LoginView" backgroundColor="0xF5FAFF">

   <fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
       public var verticalPositionTracker:Object = new Object();
   ]]>
   </fx:Script>

   </s:MobileApplication>
   ```

**MyGroup**

I then had to create a custom Group (that would contain all the data in the scroller), so that when the user scrolled down a page (changing the verticalScrollPosition), the Global variable would be updated with the new position.

```
public class AirpointGroup extends VGroup
{

    public var pageID:String;

    public function AirpointGroup()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function set verticalScrollPosition(value:Number):void{
        if (layout)
        {
            layout.verticalScrollPosition = value;
        }
        trace("The position of "+this.pageID+" has changed to "+value);
        if(value!=0)
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.verticalPositionTracker[pageID] = value;
    }
}
```

**Results.mxml (Working example)**
I then included this group in a view *with the ID of "mainContent"* (important as it allows the view to know which group to set the y-coordinate to)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components:MyView xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:components="components.*"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Tasks" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <components:MyGroup pageID="{this.title}" id="mainContent">
                  <!-- ALL CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </components:MyGroup>
</s:Scroller>


</components:MyView>
```

Comment: It is kind of bad form to take inspiration from someone else but give the "correct answer" credit to yourself.  Better: Give @alopix the "correct answer" credit and comment on his, saying "that helped a lot!  see my answer for what I finally came up with."

Comment: fair enough but alopix's answer isn't complete in that we have to keep passing through the y-coordinate. What if we go away from that page and then come back, the scroll position is lost. Further, if our application already passes data about, which it likely does, we would have to change our entire application to accommodate for this. Gave him a + and a tick even though his solution isn't complete, nor really that similar to mine... Newcomers to this thread will automatically use his solution as he has the tick

Comment: That is why you add a comment at the bottom of his.  This site isn't about coming up with complete solutions.  It is about giving thoughts and answers to help you get to your complete solution.  Especially if the question/answer is complex.